# Angular2 - Why won't :host grow vertically with its content in Safari?

Tags: css, angular, safari, host

I am developing a website in Angular2.  In the css for all of my components, I am making use of the `:host` selector.  The css there is brief and more or less identical in every component:

```
:host 
{
  position:relative;
  top:60px;
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
}
```

Most of my components are dynamically populated with data retrieved from a database, so the host element should grow with the content dynamically placed inside of it.  This works as intended in both Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari.  In Safari, the data is loaded properly, but :host doesn't grow, and as such, the black background color just cuts off at a certain point as you scroll down the page.  I should mention that the version of Safari I'm using is 9, which is certainly outdated, so for all I know, this may not even be an issue in more recent versions, but this still has to work in older versions for backwards compatibility.  Also, I've not yet tested in IE or Edge, so I'm not sure if this is an issue there or not.

So I'm just wondering why :host isn't growing with its content in (at least this older version of) Safari and if there's a way to fix it?  And I know I can just use a wrapper class in each of my components, put the background color in there instead of `:host`, and that will work(I tried it), and that's what I'll do if I have to, but I just wanted to inquire here first to see if anyone knows why I'm having this issue and if there's a way to fix it without resorting to a wrapper `div`/`class`.

Comment: Host will grow if its parent allows him.

Answer (score 0):

Angular host elements have `inline` display by default. Try changing the default display of the host element:

```
:host {
  display: block; // or any other value.
}
```

Inline elements ignore any height or width values.

See [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices#set-a-host-display-style-eg-block--inline-block-flex-unless-you-prefer-the-default-of--inline) for more explanation.

Comment: Then it would be helpful if there is any demo on stackblitz or something similar to help us answer you :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had an old, unnecessary display:flex in a :host style for a parent component that was screwing things up.  Removing that fixed the problem.